# Dynamically creating a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, appendchild, createelement

I have got a *working* table that when the button is pushed, a table is dynamically created by looping through an array and displaying that data in each cell.

However the problem arises when I am trying to add a table header for my table, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

[Here is my current working code: (although doesn't seem to work in JSFiddle?!)](http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/)

And here is the code I am trying to add: (which must be wrong)

```
var thd=document.createElement("thead");
tab.appendChild(thd);

var tr= document.createElement("tr"); 
tbdy.appendChild(tr); 

var th= document.createElement("th");
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name");
tr.appendChild(th);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: You need to set the jsfiddle to not wrap the code in an onload event. http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/1/

Comment: You forgot to "close" the input, that's why the jsFiddle is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/3/

Comment: And the header works as well as long as you fix the missing `)` in the second to last line. http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/2/. Time to learn how the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) works.

Comment: Instead of `tbdy.appendChild(tr);` you probably wanted to write
`thd.appendChild(tr);`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to avoid duplicating code. For example:

```
var columns = ["Name", "Age", "Degree"];

var thd = document.createElement("thead");
tab.appendChild(thd);

var tr = document.createElement("tr"); 
thd.appendChild(tr);

for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columns[i]));
    tr.appendChild(th);    
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ahEkH/6/